# How to control enable/disable state for a c# outlook addin mailitem ribbon button?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, ribbon

I try to find a way to enable/disable an outlook ribbon button (`Inspector mail.compose`) depending if the cursor is in the body field of the mail or not.

The behavior must be the same as the internal ribbon button like for insert links. This button should be disabled if the cursor is not in the mail message body. But I didn't find any way to do the same for custom ribbon button.

Remark: It must depend on the position of the cursor, not for a selection in the body field.

Thank for help
Reinhard

Comment: Are you asking how to enable/disable the button or how to track the cursor position?

Comment: My question is how to track the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

To track the cursor position, use Inspector.WordDocument.Application (returns Word's Application object). You can use the Application.WindowSelectionChange event.